# Facing incompatible module issue with inotify when try to install codegen

Tags: typescript, graphql, darwin, graphql-codegen

I tried to install codegen in react application using the below comment

```
npm install --save-dev @graphql-codegen/cli @graphql-codegen/typescript @graphql-codegen/typescript-operations @graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo
```

and i got the below error

```
yarn add v1.22.19
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error inotify@1.4.6: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

my node version in v14.20.0
How to resolve this issue